# Django user sign up crashes with `TypeError: 'field_name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Tags: python, django

I would like to add an additional information to user profile during registration. I've created class `Profile` and defined Django signals:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    extra = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()


post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
post_save.connect(save_user_profile, sender=User)
```

During the registration form processing I call

```
User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, extra='Extra info')
```

and got

> TypeError: 'extra' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

I've seen a lot of tutorials use this method, moreover Django documentation recommends this method. But I do not understand why it crashes for me.

Comment: You have a one-to-one relation with a User model, but not a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). Non-standard kwargs passed to [`.create_user()` only work for custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user).

Comment: So, I have to extend models.User?

Comment: Extend the user model, or not pass `extra` to `.create_user()`. The `extra` field is part of `Profile`, not part of `User`. So if you chose the second option, you create a basic `User`, then create a `Profile` with that `user` instance and the other fields.

Comment: @Evert but Profile does not have create method, hot to create it?

Comment: @Evert, I've done. But now it crashes with IntegrityError on `profile.save()`

Comment: That'd be a new question. Or rather, spent some time searching about that error and debugging.